# Importing a key of an export in es6

Tags: ecmascript-6

In def.js:

```
export const defs = {
  name: 'Joe',
  age: 30,
  id: 123
}
```

In user.js:

```
import { defs } from './def';
const { name } = defs;

console.log(name);
```

Is there a way to import defs.name right away, without importing defs first?
Something like:

```
import {defs.name} from './defs';
```

Comment: No, that's not supported in named imports.